# Ignore some directories in Git

Tags: git, gitignore

I have in my git repository this path :

```
pir-enio/src/main/java/at/ClientSide/com/audit/client
```

I want to ignore this part:

```
src/main/java/at/ClientSide/
```

because my package is `com.audit.client`.

I am wondering now where to put `.gitignore`  file in order to ignore the above path

If I put it in `main` than `.gitignore` is going to ignore all what comes after `*src*` so it is going to ignore also  `/com/audit/client` and I do not want to ignore that part.

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore this part"?

Comment: How does this question have anything to do with github or gitlab?

Answer (score 0):

You can negate excludes like:

```
pir-enio/*
!pir-enio/src/main/java/at/ClientSide/com/audit/client
```

But if You want it like this, then why You didn't started git repository in /com ?